# Detect a specific collision when more than one collision occurs with a CharacterController using OnControllerColliderHit()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my character to switch from `WalkingMovement` to `ClimbingMovement` when it collides with a Ladder. I used the `OnControllerColliderHit()` function to detect collisions because I am using CharcterController for my character.

The problem is when I collide with the ladder the character is still colliding with the Plane so it does not switch to `ClimbingMovement`. Instead it just stays in the `WalkingMovement`. So how to I detect a specific collision when more than one collision occurs with a CharacterController?

Comment: Not sure about your question. You want to determine the specific object detected by `OnControllerColliderHit`?

Comment: When my character walks over the plane(i.e, technically when colliding with plane), i set the climbMovement to false. When it collides with a ladder, i switch the climbMovement to true. But since the character remains collided with the ground while colliding with a ladder, the switch to climbMovement is not happening. It recognises only one(collision with plane) out of the two collisions(collision with plane, collision with ladder.). So how do I tell, if both plane and ladder are collided, switch climbMovement true else if only plane is collided turn off climbMovement ? @Programmer

Comment: You said plane then ground. Are these the-same in your comment? Also, in newer version of Unity, you should be able to use `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` for `CharacterController`.  Can you try both and see if they are working? I say this because you need a way to know when a collier is no longer touching to do this properly.

Comment: I'd recommend using a trigger (passable collider) for this. Ensuring the colliders touch all the while the player wants to climb is going to be way too tricky.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you. But unfortunately, `OnCollision` events don't seem to work with `CharacterController`.